# Best iphone game with source to learn from for a beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What's the best iphone game w/source code that you would recommend for a beginner to learn from?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's the best, but a famous game on iOS just went open source. **Canabalt**, https://github.com/ericjohnson/canabalt-ios

Answer (score 0):

For multiplayer (using GameKit), look at GKTank, GKRocket, and GKTapper
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=GameKit