# 2D game development

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I just wanted to know some initial things before developing 2D games. I have developed 4-5 apps for iPhone in my career and am very much familiar with programming on iphone, but this is my first time developing a 2D game. I want to develop a game in which mountains and trees etc are constantly moving in background and a man or any living thing is running forward having so many obstacle in its way. He has ability to jump over obstacle etc.

I have no idea about Cocos2d or openGLES or Quartz 2D. I guess its important to choose the best template for 2D game development otherwise i can go in the wrong direction. Please guide me who have experience in 2D game development in iPhone. Any books or links for tutorial is highly appreciated.

Comment: I remember I enjoyed [this old book](http://www.amazon.com/Tricks-Game-Programming-Gurus-Andre-Lamothe/dp/0672305070/) a while back. It's probably of little relevance to your platform and the kind of game, but look up similar/related books on game development. There are plenty. See their reviews.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251055/why-use-cocos-over-ui-kit-for-a-2d-iphone-game) seems related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this post helps...

[Best iphone game with source to learn from for a beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627378/best-iphone-game-with-source-to-learn-from-for-a-beginner/)

or the given book is also helpful

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321699424/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321699424)